# Autocorrelation in daily bond returns

Tags: fixed-income, returns

I've been examining the returns of a few government bond series around the world. I found out that some have a positive daily autocorrelation. It's not big, but still seems at odds with efficiency. These are bonds of developed countries too. I'd expect a possibly negative autocorrelation at best, as you see in the U.S. for instance. Not sure where it is coming from..Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Which bonds in particular and Ill try and replicate and see how large the AR is.

Comment: They are in the order of 0.1. R^2 is low, around 1%. But, they are highly significant.

Comment: It is also robust to subsamples. There's no reason for it to be there even if you can't act on it.